# Nifi: unable to rename from './data/flow.xml.gz.new.xml.gz' to './data/flow.xml.gz'

Tags: vagrant, apache-nifi, persistent-volumes

I'm mounting a volume in a Vagrant box, containing my flow.xml.gz file, to a Nifi container running in a Kubernetes cluster. When the Nifi container spins up, my flow.xml.gz file loads as expected.

The problem occurs when I sync the volume in Vagrant to a directory on my host machine, such that the flow.xml.gz file should be synced between the directory on my host machine, the volume in Vagrant, and a directory in the Nifi container. I restart the pod and get the error below; and the flow.xml.gz file is mysteriously deleted from Vagrant and my host machine.

```
org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiCoreException: Unable to start Flow Controller.
        at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:88)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1068)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:572)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.contextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:997)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:746)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1449)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1414)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:911)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.doStart(GzipHandler.java:426)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:1057)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:159)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:71)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:303)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Attempted 5 times but unable to rename from './data/flow.xml.gz.new.xml.gz' to './data/flow.xml.gz'
        at org.apache.nifi.util.file.FileUtils.renameFile(FileUtils.java:504)
        at org.apache.nifi.persistence.StandardXMLFlowConfigurationDAO.save(StandardXMLFlowConfigurationDAO.java:171)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService.load(StandardFlowService.java:541)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:72)
        ... 38 common frames omitted
```

I thought the perhaps there was a permissions problem, but the permissions on flow.xml.gz are wide open, and the owner is set to the user running Nifi. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using rsync syncing or virtualbox sharing for the folder? Virtualbox shared folders regularly give me similar issues with the linux guests unable to move/rename files on the Windows host shared folder.

Comment: @Cyrus I'm using VirtualBox shared folders

Comment: Then it's probably the fact that renaming open files works on linux filesystems but not Windows, which I'm guessing your host and shared directory are. You'll probably want a Linux filesystem on the  mounted persistent volume. In either case, I would not try to sync the flow.xml.gz while NiFi is running.